# How to create a concave curving sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to clip out a concave edge on the right side of a div (to make a curving sidebar, ultimately). I have struggled with CSS to make this happen.

I got quite close by wrapping *the rest of the content* in a div with `border-radius-top-left` and `border-radius-bottom-left`, creating the illusion of a curving sidebar:

```
.contentMask {
  margin-left: 12%;
  border-top-left-radius: 12% 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 11% 47%;
}
```

[image]

The result, however, does not follow a curve in the manner i desire - it's more like an ellipse with a very flat edge. I can't get it right. Is there a way to create a sidebar like this, following an arc I can define?

Edit for posterity: I got a bit closer to what I wanted by an additional hack. I made the content *taller than the screen* with extra vertical space, then used negative top margin to scroll it back into place. Then I made the outer container of the whole thing `height: 100vh` and `overflow: hidden`, thus allowing me to basically clip off part of the curve and achieve the arc I wanted. Only problem now is I can't really add box-shadow this way.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the inspiration of what ur trying to achieve ?

Comment: Sure - added a picture.

Comment: I've created a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-bash-8qv4r?file=/index.html

is this what ur looking for ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984497/border-corner-shape-scoop-doesnt-work this answer your question

Comment: @prograk thank you but no that still has a gradient - it doesn't really look anything like the picture I have in the post. Sorry!!

Comment: @Usiel no those are just the corners - not the sides. I haven't been able to find a way to use that technique to make a sidebar like the one I have pictured. If you know how, make a fiddle and post it as an answer!

Comment: you want svg morph in curve shape like awwwards websites? if yes i can help you

Answer (score 0):

The below code might helpful for your situation using background-image property.

```
div {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: green;
   background-image: radial-gradient(45% 75% at 100% 50%, red 75%, transparent 75%);
}
```

Also you can use clip-path property like below but the curvature might need more points to make like a perfect curve

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 84% 36%, 84% 65%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 35%, 0 0);
```

[check the fiddle to see how it works](https://jsfiddle.net/ymjqbrsa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**Hello** to make a concave side of a div, yes, you can do it using gradient, of course the div will still be square or rectangular. Look at the following example, it is based on this post [Border corner shape scoop doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984497/border-corner-shape-scoop-doesnt-work)

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(
      100% 50%,
      circle,
      transparent 45%,
      steelblue 15%
    )
    no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px, 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using clipping path and something like https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ but I don't think it will work out how you want. Your best bet would probably be to create the image as a background then use display flex or fixed depending on how you want to use it. Or if you want the content to follow the shape maybe even a combination of the two, not sure how that would work out.

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
section {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20vw;
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/vHC8KpjC/test.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>Main content</main>
</section>
```

Comment: Now I understand what is he looking for